# Interface inheritance and property hiding trouble

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I recently introduced an interface on a base class for unit-testing purposes and ran into a weird problem. This is the minimal reproducible scenario:

```
interface IBase
{
    string Text { get; }
}

interface IChild : IBase
{
}

class Base : IBase
{
    public string Text { get { return "Base"; }}
}

class Child : Base, IChild
{
    public new string Text { get { return "Child"; }}
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var child = new Child();
    Console.WriteLine(child.Text); // Outputs "Child"
    Console.WriteLine((child as Base).Text); // Outputs "Base"
    Console.WriteLine(((child as Base) as IBase).Text); // Outputs "Child"
}
```

The output of the first two `Console.WriteLine` commands is logical, but I fail to accept the output of the last one, it even outputs `Child` when using a temporary variable of type `Base`. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

**UPDATE**

By removing the interface `IChild`, `((child as Base) as IBase).Text` suddenly results in `"Base"`. Which makes me conclude that, as long as `Child` implements `IBase` (directly or through interface inheritance) the result will be `"Child"` instead of `"Base"`.

This can get really tricky when you refactor a method in an other class to take an argument of `IBase` instead of `Base`, as it suddenly results in different behavior.

Comment: You should of course just avoid this mess. Needing a `new` member is never a good sign.

Comment: In fact, that `new` property was dead code and threw an exception. It was never used because the code always used the base type. Adding the base interface brought that dead code to life :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you are casting here:

`(child as Base)` to `Base` and you're using `Base`'s `Text` field. It's clear.

But in here:

`(child as Base) as IBase` you are casting `Child` to `Base` and then to `IBase` which means you are casting `Child` to `IBase`, which means `Child`'s `Text` will be displayed. You are not changing the of underlying object by using `as`.

So `(child as Base) as IBase` here is the same as `child as IBase`.

EDIT:

Edited question does not change the fact that this answer is correct. As @InBetween said it is just changing the way how implementation of `Text` property is resolved. So `Child` class no longer implements `IBase` directly, so now `Base`'s `Text` would be used as best match. Basically it is just using first class implementing `IBase`